# between operator for timestamps in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

I have a form to pick up dates from calender. That form will pass start date and end date. My database table stores date in time-stamp format. I have to create a query to pick records from database table between start date and end date. How can I make a query? I have tried the code below, but which is not working.

```
 if(isset($_POST['filter']))
    {
        $sid=$_POST['sid'];
        $start= date("dMY",strtotime($_POST['start']));
        $end= date("dMY",strtotime($_POST['end']));

        $res=$db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `logfile` WHERE `site_id`=".$sid." AND (date('dMY',`timestamp`) BETWEEN $start AND $end)");


    }
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, note the difference between "datetime" and "timestamp".  For many reasons, "timestamp" is usually the *least* preferred.  Use "datetime" whenever possible:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html  IMHO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forcing PHP and MySQL to do a lot of useless date/time string<->native conversions for no reason.

Why not simply have:

```
$start = strtotime($_POST['start']);

SELECT ... WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($start) AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Matei Mihai said you don't need to convert `$_POST['start']` and `$_POST['end']` to timestamp format and you must enclose date columns in quotes.

Also you need to convert date in MySQL compatible format like `'2012-08-01'`.

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM `logfile` 
 WHERE `site_id`=".$sid." AND 
       (date('dMY',`timestamp`) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')");
```

Comment: '$start' AND '$end)' please replace it with '$start' AND '$end') single quote require inside of the bracket

Comment: date have always single or double quote required@MateiMihai

Answer (score 0):

if `$_POST['start']` and `$_POST['end']` are already in timestamp format, just don't change them. In other case just convert the string in timestamp:

```
$start = strtotime($_POST['start']); // where $_POST['start'] might be 2012/08/07
$end = strtotime($_POST['end']);


$res=$db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM logfile WHERE site_id=".$sid." AND date BETWEEN $start AND $end");
```